# How does OpenCL's address-space information propagate in LLVM?

Tags: clang, opencl, llvm, memory-address, llvm-ir

Goal: to add a new attribute on source code and propagate it through the Machine Level code to achieve further optimizations of custom address spaces.

How can I follow OpenCL's approach to add a new attribute like this? I have often thought that this mechanism should be “mostly” what I need, with `address-space ‘0’` simply being `“default”`.